# Error when AWS Lambda trying to list DynamoDb tables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I failed to get the following logic to work on AWS Lambda using Java:

1) When there is a new object created in S3 bucket, trigger a lambda function (written in java)

2) In this lambda function, list all the DynamoDB tables.

3) Create a table if there is none.

4) Write the S3 object's details as item into DynamoDB.

I only get item #1 working. when it reach item #2, I encounter a permission related error below.

Any help or suggestion?

The permission that i use is "Basic with DynamoDB", which has the following permission:

[image] [image]

> START RequestId: e9ab5aba-307b-11e5-9663-3188c327cf5e
>   fileSize: 1024, DateTime:1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Zs3Key   : HappyFace.jpgAWS credential profiles file not found in the given path: /home/sbx_user1052/.aws/credentials: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS credential profiles file not found in the given path: /home/sbx_user1052/.aws/credentials
>       at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.ProfilesConfigFileLoader.loadProfiles(ProfilesConfigFileLoader.java:45)
>       at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.loadProfiles(ProfilesConfigFile.java:176)
>       at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.(ProfilesConfigFile.java:112)
>       at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.(ProfilesConfigFile.java:92)
>       at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:123)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1763)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.listTables(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1208)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.ListTablesCollection.firstPage(ListTablesCollection.java:46)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.PageIterator.next(PageIterator.java:45)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.IteratorSupport.nextResource(IteratorSupport.java:79)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.IteratorSupport.hasNext(IteratorSupport.java:47)
>       at com.TriggerDynamoDB.handleRequest(TriggerDynamoDB.java:68)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>
> END RequestId: e9ab5aba-307b-11e5-9663-3188c327cf5e
>   REPORT RequestId: e9ab5aba-307b-11e5-9663-3188c327cf5e  Duration: 3294.97 ms    Billed Duration: 3300 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB

Code is as follows:

```
public class TriggerDynamoDB implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {

public String handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
     LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
     try {           
         S3EventNotificationRecord record = s3event.getRecords().get(0);
         // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
         String srcKey = record.getS3().getObject().getKey().replace('+', ' ');
            srcKey = URLDecoder.decode(srcKey, "UTF-8");

         long fileSize = record.getS3().getObject().getSizeAsLong();
         DateTime datetime = record.getEventTime(); 

         logger.log("fileSize: " + fileSize + ", DateTime:" + datetime);
         logger.log("s3Key   : " + srcKey);

         DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()));
         //Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("dimensionFile");

         TableCollection<ListTablesResult> tables = dynamoDB.listTables();
         Iterator<Table> iterator = tables.iterator();

         while (iterator.hasNext()) { // this is where the error was thrown
             Table table = iterator.next();
             System.out.println(table.getTableName());
         }                    
         return "Ok";
     } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [ProfileCredentialsProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html) you're passing to the AmazonDynamoDBClient constructor attempts to load credentials from the `~/.aws/credentials` file. This file doesn't exist on the host where your Lambda function is being run, hence the exception. This provider is mainly intended for things like integration tests that run on your dev machine and use your personal IAM user credentials.

On Lambda you want the [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.html). This provider will load temporary credentials for the IAM Role associated with your Lambda function from environment variables that Lambda sets before invoking your code.

If you use the no-argument constructor for the AmazonDynamoDBClient, it will default to using the [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) to pull credentials. This provider checks environment variables, Java system properties, `~/.aws/credentials`, and the EC2 Instance Metadata Service (in that order), and should pick up credentials whether you're running locally or on Lambda.

Comment: Hi David, with no-argument constuctor, i received a different error: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: BR5G9E5ITKCDCUAACUN17CRG93VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)

Comment: And if i use InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider , i received another error:com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load credentials from Amazon EC2 metadata service

Comment: Oh oh! i found the root cause and solution. Within lambda container, credentials are available in the Environment, hence all i need was just use EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(). Thanks for laying down the clue here David!

Comment: Could you help to edit your answer with "EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()"? i'll accept yours as answer, since you're the one who hinted somewhere around this.

Comment: Ah, nice! I was working for me with the default credentials provider chain, so I assumed it was picking them up via the instance metadata service. Edit coming!

Comment: This is for node.js, but it has bitten me a couple times and this is one of the limited results on the issue.  If you're seeing this in lambda node and IAM and everything else is good, check that you're *not* passing key/secret.  Let the aws sdk pick these up.  See the final section of this for more info - https://gist.github.com/cmawhorter/3cf67164414c4a97fcd8

Answer (score 0):

you need dynamoDb listTables permission on the operations.
Also you need to correctly specify the resource: as **"*"** not **""**

Here is a valid policy including ListTables:

> { "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Sid":
>   "Stmt1428341300017", "Action": [ "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
>   "dynamodb:GetItem", "dynamodb:PutItem", "dynamodb:Query",
>   "dynamodb:Scan", "dynamodb:UpdateItem", "dynamodb:ListTables" ],
>   "Effect": "Allow", "Resource": "*" }, { "Sid": "", "Resource": "*",
>   "Action": [ "logs:CreateLogGroup", "logs:CreateLogStream",
>   "logs:PutLogEvents" ], "Effect": "Allow" } ] }

Also, for future reference, read through/try this out:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies_testing-policies.html

Comment: I had "dynamoDb:ListTables" as part of the previous testings, it failed on the same reason. I think this is a different issue, because the error message sounds like lambda couldnt find any credential file at all.

Comment: The "*" asterisk is there, i think i was using a quote, and it hide the *. I updated the Json into a Picture instead. Still, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: so this is still failing for you?

Comment: Yah, it failed and still failing. i checked the aws source code at below link line 47, and i think i must have misconfigure something, but i dont know what is it:
https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/HEAD/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/internal/ProfilesConfigFileLoader.java?line=47

Answer (score 0):

Go to Console Home > IAM > Groups > YOUR GROUP > Permissions > Attach Policy

Add AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess, AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB

Go to Console Home > IAM > Groups > YOUR GROUP > Users > Add Users to Group (Add YOUR USER here to the group)

Go to Console Home > IAM > Users > YOUR USER > Create Access Key

```
BasicAWSCredentials b = new BasicAWSCredentials("Access Key ID","Secret Access Key");           
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
```

use

```
AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build()
```

this function itself will get credentials from environment